# What standard WPF control should I use?

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls

I am trying the master-detail presentation in my app: when an item in a listbox is selected, its details are displayed in an adjacent control.

This control will have a list of measurements such as height, width, weight, etc. It will also have some small graphics such as a green or red dot or a medium sized image. It will also have some rich text.

Which STANDARD WPF control should I use to contain all these elements. I am thinking of using a listbox but wonder if there are better controls to use.

My main consideration is ease of coding, then possibly efficiency of the code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A listbox indicates a list of items that can be tailored using a DataTemplate for appearence. In this case you are showing the details of a selected item. I would actually use a container such as a Grid nested in your current UI and have a set of stackpanel including the details of the selected item.

```
 <Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock>Detail1</TextBlock>
            <TextBox></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock>Detail2</TextBlock>
            <TextBox></TextBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This is only one suggestion but the point is to use a container and use a set of controls in the containers - textblock,textbox,checkboxes(boolean details), etc... this will allow you to use any control type necessary to represent the specific data field of the selected item.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use a listbox unless you have a collection of similar items, and you want one or more items to be 'selected' at some point. It sounds like that is not what you want for the details part.

You do have a collection, which is shown in your master list.  You should bind the SelectedItem in your master list to a property in your viewmodel.  Then you can bind that same property to the details section of your UI. When the selection in the master list changes, your details UI will automatically update to reflect the changes.

```
<ListBox x:Name="masterList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"></ListBox>
<UserControl x:Name="detailsControl" DataContext="{Binding MySelectedItem}"> </UserControl >
```